# nextcord error, nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

I started nextcord to develop a discord bot, but I don't understand it well from the beginning.

When I type !youtube with slash_command in discord, I get this result, but I don't know where I went wrong..

GUILD_ID & Token deleted for secure

```
from nextcord import Interaction, SlashOption, ChannelType
from nextcord.abc import GuildChannel
from nextcord.ext import commands
import nextcord

GUILD_ID = 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[GUILD_ID])
async def youtube(interaction : Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("hi")

bot.run('')
```

**result**
Ignoring exception in command None:
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "youtube" is not found

Comment: Slash commands use '/', not your command_prefix

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs
  I just tested it and I get the same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type / in your message field in discord should pop up something where you can select bots and commands. Click on your bot's icon and check if your 'youtube' command is there. If yes just click it and hit enter.
Also you can remove this line: `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')` if you only use Slash Commands because they work without a custom command prefix

Comment: I solved it by myself. 
`client = nextcord.Client()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the name in the `@client.slash_command()` decorator. The name of the asynchronous function does not matter.

Your code but working:

```
from nextcord import Interaction, SlashOption, ChannelType
from nextcord.abc import GuildChannel
from nextcord.ext import commands
import nextcord

GUILD_ID = 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@bot.slash_command(name="youtube", description="whatever description you want(not required)",guild_ids=[GUILD_ID])
async def youtube(interaction : Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("hi")

bot.run('')
```

`
The description of the slash command can be whatever you want.